# Using ListPlot3D with custom colours

Tags: plotting, color

I would like to use `ListPlot3D` to make a 3D plot using a file containing the following information (4 columns):

```
 x,  y,  f(x,y),  w(x,y).
```

Here `x` and `y` are the coordinates in the Cartesian framework, `f(x,y)` is some function that depends on `x` and `y`, and `w(x,y)` is another function that represents weights of the function `f`. So for each data point in `f(x,y)` we have the corresponding weight `w(x,y)`.

To plot the function f(x,y) I do the following:

```
f = Import["file.dat", "Table"];
ListPlot3D[f]
```

and that is fine.

Now I want to have this plot but with colours determined by the weights, i.e. for each point in "f" I would like to have the colour determined by the value of "w". Suppose "w" takes values from 0 to 1, I want that 0 corresponds to "blue" and 1 corresponds to "red", and all values in-between is the gradient between "blue" and "red". For example, if I have a row in "file.dat": 0, 1, 10, 0.5, I would like a 3D plot where at (x,y)=(0,1) the value of the function is f=10 and the colour of this point is 50% blue and 50% red. Can you suggest please how to do this in Mathematica?

Comment: `ColorFunction` and `Blend` are the two functions you want to look into.

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve this using the option `ColorFunction`of ListPlot3D.

We first create test some data, then define the color function and finally make the plot:

```
dat = Flatten[
   Table[{x, y, Sin[x y], Sin[x ]^2 Sin[y ]^2}, {x, 0, Pi, Pi/20}, {y,
      0, Pi, Pi/20}], 1];

col = Interpolation[dat[[All, {1, 2, 4}]]];
colfunction := Function[{x, y, z}, RGBColor[col[x, y], 0, 1 - col[x, y]]];

ListPlot3D[dat[[All, 1 ;; 3]], ColorFunction -> colfunction, 
 ColorFunctionScaling -> False]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! A follow up question regarding your example: how to use opacity in such a way that it is applied selectively to different colours. More specifically, I would like to have red colour with opacity 1.0 and blue colour with opacity 0.1. What is the best to do this?

Answer (score 1):

To achieve: " red colour with opacity 1.0 and blue colour with opacity 0.1" use the following:

```
dat = Flatten[
   Table[{x, y, Sin[x y], Sin[x]^2 Sin[y]^2}, {x, 0, Pi, Pi/20}, {y, 
     0, Pi, Pi/20}], 1];

col = Interpolation[dat[[All, {1, 2, 4}]]];
colfunction := 
  Function[{x, y, z}, {Opacity[0.1 (1 - col[x, y]) + col[x, y]], 
    RGBColor[col[x, y], 0, 1 - col[x, y]]}];

ListPlot3D[dat[[All, 1 ;; 3]], ColorFunction -> colfunction, 
 ColorFunctionScaling -> False]
```

[image]